# Typescript: Infer type without extends within interface scope

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I'm not sure if this is even declarative enough but I need to infer type inside interface scope and use it within same scope as argument for method. Here is simple example

```
interface Prop {
    x: infer U,
    // ^^^^^^^ store type coming from 'x'
    validate: (x: U) => U
    //            ^ use type
}

interface IState {
    [key: string]: Prop
}
```

and usecase

```
const state:IState = {
    asString: {
        x: '',
        validate: value => value + ' is string',
        //        ^^^^^ string
    },
    asBoolean: {
        x: true,
        validate: value => !value;
        //        ^^^^^ boolean
    }
}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly what you want but you could do:

```
interface Prop<U> {
    x: U,
    validate: (x: U) => U
}

function makeProp<U>(x: U, validate: (x: U) => U): Prop<U> {
    return { x, validate }
}

const state = {
    asString: makeProp('', value => value + ' is string'),
    asBoolean: makeProp(true, value => !value)
}
// Here, 'state' is of type: { asString: Prop<string>, asBoolean: Prop<boolean> }
```